# Match first line containing head tag and store in variable as a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a new meta tag to an html file from an external php file in the same directory.
I will test for the presence of my meta tag with jQuery then call the php function via ajax if the meta does not exist.
So in subsequent page loads i am good.

I am trying to build a function to do this, but could use a little help with one aspect of it.
I could not guarantee how the line containing the opening head tag would be written, so i guess this will need to be a regex of some form.
Please see the code below :

```
// So the line with the opening head tag may for arguments sake look like this one below :
// <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" data-cast-api-enabled="true"><head>  <link id="css-680430062" rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-core-vfl8iz0yT.css">

function insert_into_file($file_path, $text, $after = true) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file_path);
    $insert_marker = ""; // this should be the line containing the opening head tag saved to the variable as a string
    $new_contents = preg_replace($insert_marker, ($after) ? '$0' . $text : $text . '$0', $contents);
return file_put_contents($file_path, $new_contents);
```

}

Comment: These are static html or static php files each with their own individual headers?

Comment: Yes i believe they always will be.

Comment: Would you be willing to have the code crawl the site instead of user involvement via javascript? (it's possible with AJAX in Javascript, but it means you'll have to open every page).

Comment: Also what's the content of the potentially existing meta we're looking for? Just the beginning of the content... so something like 'content="Copyright' or 'content="My Website'...

Comment: I don't intend user involvement, i was going to fire of the meta existence check on doc ready, and act or not... The new meta tag is for Facebook plugin adim <meta property="fb:admins" content="605672514">. I have the dynamic generation of the users id for the meta tag covered, before i pass it to the php script as a string via ajax.

Comment: Why not use `<head>`?

Comment: @MikeM Hey, that's what I did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the path from regular passers by we'll base64 encode it. Anyone who knows what this is when they recognize it might try to base64 decode it and inject something like .htaccess, this will at least make them work for it if they're trying to hack your processing page. For this example, you'll need pass `var pathname = window.location.pathname;` base64 encoded via ajax to the processor.

Check out [jquery base64](https://github.com/yckart/jquery.base64.js)

**Note**
This is not tested and depends on several factors including write permissions for the directories by the Apache user on the system. (I'm also assuming you're using apache when I'm checking for the .htaccess). If I were running this on a live website I would also do some sort of a check to make sure that the IP from which it was run was my own and whitelist myself, that way if Googlebot or Yandex hits your site you don't start taxing your server.

You could also make it update a log so if the page has already been changed, have it check the log to see if it there, that way you won't run the script twice. (That's just been a little picky though.)

**The Processor**

```
<?php
//this assumes the page is base64 encoded in javascript or jquery.
if(!empty($_GET['p'])){
    $path_to_page = base64_decode($_GET['p']);
    if(preg_match('!\.(php|htm[l]?)$!',$path_to_page)){
        $path_to_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/$path_to_page";
        if(!is_file($path_to_file)){
            //if they passed something else, then 
            exit();
        } else {

            //we're trying to prevent injection
            if(!empty($_GET['id'])&&preg_match('!^\d+$!',$_GET['id'])){
                $user_id = $_GET['id'];
            } else {
                exit(); 
            }
            //open the file in read/write mode
            if($fp = fopen($path_to_file, 'w+')){

            //pull the page into a var for checking
            $page = fread($fp, filesize($path_to_file));

            if(!preg_match('!property\s*=\s*["\']fb:admins!is',$page)){
            //if it doesn't exist, then add it.
                $page = preg_replace('!</head>!i',"<meta property=\"fb:admins\" content=\"$user_id\">\n\n</head>",$page);
                if(fwrite($fp, $page))
                {
                    echo 'success';
                } else {
                    echo 'failure';}
                }

            fclose($fp);
           } else {
             echo 'failure';
           }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

To put it directly after the head tag you would use:

```
$page = preg_replace('!(<head[^>]+>)!i',"$1\n\n<meta property=\"fb:admins\" content=\"$user_id\">\n",$page);
```

Comment: Forgot to comment out my single quote in my regex.

Comment: This looks great, thanks. Just one issue. It appears in my test to place the new meta tag above the opening head tag instead of below it.

Comment: Right, I updated my code, sorry about that. Added a slash in </head> and also closed the tag on the search and the replacement, because it also would match the new html5 </header> tag without the closing symbol. I also added an accommodation in case there were spaces or tabs in an existing property declaration.

Comment: Almost there, i wish i was better at regex :-(. What it's currently doing is creating the meta tag just above the closing head tag, but after any content in the head like script calls etc.

Comment: That's what you want. As long as it's in the head tag you're good with older implementations of xhtml. Technically it can be anywhere if you're using a doctype like html5.

Comment: Should we not be looking for the end of line the opening head tag exists, and replacing that entire line with the line and then the meta tag..?

Comment: In my hard coded tests earlier it does not seem to work if placed after the script calls.

Comment: Order in the head tag doesn't matter. The browser or bots will use the meta statements based on their intentions.

Comment: Do we need to add the app_id as well?https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/

Comment: I have to head out, but will be back later.

Comment: Technically yes there should be an app id meta tag, but for my users simplicity, id rather avoid forcing them to create an app. So i provide a hard coded arbitrary app id, and this just produces a console warning as opposed to an error while maintaining all the functionality, and comments can still be moderated as long as this meta tag were dealing with is present.

Comment: I've added an update that shows the code to add it directly after a head tag that potentially contains attributes.